# Extract data from specific cells in multiple excel files - R

Tags: r, excel, lapply, readxl

I need to extract data (date, time) from two cells (E6:E7) from multiple excel files and then store that data into a data frame (with separate columns for date and time).

See below for the code I've tried.

```
setwd("C:/Users/tsamuels/Desktop/PDRA - Collins/growth_rate_folder")
file.list <- list.files(path=".", pattern="\\d.xlsx$")
df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel(path=".", sheet = 1, range = "E6:E7", col_names = FALSE,
                                        col_types = NULL))
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not using `read_excel` and you did not provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610) so I could not test it, but you could try this.

```
df.list <- lapply(file.list, read_excel, sheet=1, range="E6:E7", col_names=FALSE, col_types = NULL))
```

Comment: That partially worked! I've now got a tibble for the data from each excel file, how would I get all of that data into a single tibble?

Comment: [this should help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list) or [this (row bind)](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.12.8/topics/rbindlist)

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions about your files and how you want your output:

```
files <- list.files('.', pattern = '*.xlsx', recursive = TRUE)
df1 <- lapply(files, 
              function(x) {readxl::read_xlsx(x, sheet = 1, range = "E6:E7", col_names = FALSE)}) %>% 
  bind_cols %>% 
  t %>% 
  data.frame

colnames(df1) <- c('date', 'time')
rownames(df1) <- files
```

Here `bind_cols` (or do you need `bind_rows`?) will take your list of dataframes and combine them